# updating JAVA keystore/truststore with new certificate/key when wildfly vault used to mask the keystore/truststore password

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keytool, jks, jceks

By default we want to mask the keystore password using wildfly vault(using vault.sh) and configure appropriately in the standalone.xml. Now if we want add addtional key to the keystore, what are the options available? I am seeing vault.sh provides only option to add or remove the confidential information but not to retrieve it(may be for security reasons). As wildlfly able to retrieve the actual password from masked vaule, it should be possible programatically. But I want some script or utility to do that. Please let me know how to address this.

simple query is How to access the JKS keystore to add new key if the keystore password is protected by wildfly vault?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this.